# How can I sort 2D array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How can I sort 2D array with JavaScript?

I have any array like this:

```
arr = [["123", "2017-07-11 15:00", '1'],
      ["124","2017-07-04 16:00", '1'],
      ["125","2017-07-05 12:00", '1'],
      ["126","2017-07-04 21:00", '1'],
      ["127","2017-07-03 02:00", '1'],
      ["128","2017-07-05 11:00", '1'],
      ["129","2017-07-05 14:00", '1']]
```

And I want to sort by the second element (arr[1])
How Can I do that?

I tired this before:

```
let b = arr.map(x=> x[1]).sort();
console.log(b);
```

And this is my console result:

```
["2017-07-03 02:00", 
"2017-07-04 16:00", 
"2017-07-04 21:00", 
"2017-07-05 11:00", 
"2017-07-05 12:00", 
"2017-07-05 14:00", 
"2017-07-11 15:00"]
```

But this is my expected result:

```
[["127", "2017-07-03 02:00", '1'], 
["124","2017-07-04 16:00", '1'], 
["126","2017-07-04 21:00", '1'], 
["128","2017-07-05 11:00", '1'], 
["125","2017-07-05 12:00", '1'], 
["129","2017-07-05 14:00", '1'], 
["123","2017-07-11 15:00", '1']
```

Comment: You need to sort on the *original* array, and access the second item of the sub-arrays inside the sort function.

Comment: Probably a more appropriate duplicate since it handles date sorting, not string sorting... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const input = [["123", "2017-07-11 15:00", '1'],["124","2017-07-04 16:00", '1'],["125","2017-07-05 12:00", '1'],["126","2017-07-04 21:00", '1'],["127","2017-07-03 02:00", '1'],["128","2017-07-05 11:00", '1'],["129","2017-07-05 14:00", '1']]

// Sort.
const sort = x => x.sort((A, B) => {
  const dateA = new Date(A[1])
  const dateB = new Date(B[1])
  return dateA - dateB
})

// Output.
const output = sort(input)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Comment: If it's not a date formate, how can I sort my array?

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort()` expects a `number`. So for `numbers`: the same strategy applies. For `strings`: `numbers` must be passed manually based on `> / < / ==` comparison. There are examples of each in the documentation I linked @Lynn

Answer (score 0):

since `arr[1]` is a date you need to compare them using `new Date()` like :

```js
const arr = [
  ["123", "2017-07-11 15:00", '1'],
  ["124", "2017-07-04 16:00", '1'],
  ["125", "2017-07-05 12:00", '1'],
  ["126", "2017-07-04 21:00", '1'],
  ["127", "2017-07-03 02:00", '1'],
  ["128", "2017-07-05 11:00", '1'],
  ["129", "2017-07-05 14:00", '1']
]

const result = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(a[1]) - new Date(b[1])
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Sort functions should not return true or false.

Comment: @Archer thx for the hint , i just updated the answer

Comment: What if it's not a date?

Comment: @Lynn if it's not, you can do `return a[0] - b[0]` or check [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!!!